# How can I switch themes and still be able to show the Maintain same contents?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two themes installed on a wordpress website. I have moved all my non-theme specific functions into a plugin as recommended and all is working well except customizer.php which was included in my functions.php file. I moved it away from functions.php into the plugin. The customizer contents showed when first theme was activated but won't show when I switched to the other theme. Below are code snippets for reference:

***I included customizer.php into my plugin using the code below***

```
require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/customizer.php' );
```

***Below is the panel that controls the logo***

```
if ( class_exists( 'WP_Customize_Panel' ) ):

    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_general', array(
        'priority' => 29,
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'title' => __( 'General options', 'gswmi' )
    ));

    /* LOGO */
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_logo', array(
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'themeslug_logo',
        array(
        'label' => __( 'Logo' ),
        'section' => 'title_tagline',
        'settings' => 'site_logo',
        'priority' => 1,
        )
    )); endif;
```

***The logo and contents show when the first theme is activated***
[image]

***But won't show when the second theme is activated***
[image]

I have tried different fixes, even deleting the ***text domain*** in the customizer.php code, none seemed to work. I want to be able to switch themes and still be able to show the same contents in the customizer and the frontend irrespective of the theme activated. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to sort it, thanks to some articles I found online (credits below).

By default, my setting's type above is `'theme_mod'`

Theme mods are stored in a single array in the options table in the database, one field per theme. In my case, i found all the theme customizations in a single array under theme_mods_(mythemename) in wp_options table in my database. As you can guess, this is not good for performance.

To make my logo and other settings readily availabe irrspective of the theme I use, I just had to change the setting type to `'option'` from `'theme_mod'` which is the default setting type.

But what’s the difference? To try to keep this simple:

1. **Theme Modifications(Theme Mod)** represent what’s available for a specific theme. WordPress saves all options managed by The Customizer as a single array in the database.
2. **Options** are available to any theme and/or any plugin. In contrast to the The Customizer, WordPress saves each value as a single record in the database.

***Update code below***

```
if ( class_exists( 'WP_Customize_Panel' ) ):

$wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_general', array(
    'priority' => 29,
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'title' => __( 'General options', 'gswmi' )
));

/* LOGO */
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_logo', array(
    'type'              => 'option',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'themeslug_logo',
    array(
    'label' => __( 'Logo' ),
    'section' => 'title_tagline',
    'settings' => 'site_logo',
    'priority' => 1,
    )
)); endif;
```

The above Setting’s value will get its own column inside the WP_OPTIONS table and there will be a performance boost when the value is accessed for outputting in the frontend.

***Credits:***

https://www.usablewp.com/learn-wordpress/wordpress-customizer/theme-mods-vs-options-in-wordpress/

https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-options/